# what is the use of assigning a value to a variable outside the for loop in scala

Tags: scala, for-loop

so, I am trying for loop in Scala. The code is below

```scala
val x = 5
for (x <- 1 until 10) {
  println("the value is"  + x)
}
```

The output is

```
the value is1
the value is2
the value is3
the value is4
the value is5
the value is6
the value is7
the value is8
the value is9
```

my question 1 is as it iterating thru the loop from 1 to 10. what is the use of x=5 then?
my question 2 is as far as understand in scala Val is immutable and var is mutable so why it is not throwing an error when the value x kept on changing?

Comment: Your questions are to the point. `x` has no use inside the loop, and will always be the value `5`. However, the for-comprehension introduces a new scope, creating a new `val x` which is bound on each iteration to the successive values.

Comment: `val x = 5` is dead code, it isn't good for anything. Just remove it, the output will stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala's `for` loop is syntactic sugar that desugars to the following (more or less):

```
val x = 5

(1 until 10).foreach { x =>
  println("the value is" + x)
}
```

Which is (again essentially) equivalent to:

```
val x = 5

val myFunc: Int => Unit = { x =>
  println("the value is" + x)
}

(1 until 10).foreach(myFunc)
```

This syntax makes it a little clearer that the `x` is a new variable that shadows the outer `x` in the new scope introduced by the function definition.

So in short, the two `x` variables are completely different because they have different scopes, and if you print `x` after the `for` loop, you'll still get `5`.

Answer (score 0):

not just in scala but in other programming languages as well local or inner variable precedes outer level(eg. class/ object) variable.

```
object VarlPrecedence {

  val name = "object level"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val name = "method level"
    println(name)
  }
}
```

output

```
method level
```

In your example, inner `x` is being used to iterate over the `Range`. Unlike you think the outer `x` is still immutable but unused.

Comment: There's no indication in the question that the first `x` is a class-level variable, and whether it is or not isn't really relevant—the important thing is that the `for` loop introduces a new scope.